# Which tool or technology is best for EHR (Electronic Health Record) website

Tags: website, php, asp.net

I am going to make the website of EHR which maintain the history of patient, I am little bit confuse about tool or technology, kindly suggest me which tool or technology will be the best one for these websites.

```
PHP
Java
Asp .net
Asp Classic
```

Or suggest me some other when which will helpful for me.

Comment: Super User is for questions about using your personal computer. Not development questions. Stack Overflow is for programming questions - if you have a *specific* problem you need solving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a correct tool, only the correct use of a tool.
Use the one you are most comfortable with.